Memory Issues with Dissimilarity Matrix in TraMineR for Large Dataset
I am working with a large dataset of over 2 million individuals, with varying sequence lengths, for sequence analysis using the TraMineR package in R for the first time. When I try to compute the dissimilarity matrix using optimal matching (OM), R either crashes due to a fatal error or I get the following error message:
Error in seqdist(cci.new, method = "OM", indel = 1, sm = cost_values,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Here’s what I have tried so far:

Slicing the dataset: I subset the dataset to process smaller chunks of a few thousand individuals at a time.

Ensuring same sequence length: I ensured that all sequences in the slice have the same length to avoid issues related to different sequence lengths.

Reducing the number of states: I have reduced the number of sequence states to 6

I have tried working on a machine with more power


Despite this, I am unable to analyze more than a few thousand individuals at once without encountering the errors mentioned above.
Is there a more efficient way to handle large datasets with TraMineR, particularly for dissimilarity matrix computation with OM? Are there any specific techniques or parameters that could help reduce memory usage, prevent the negative length vector error, or speed up computation? Or is TramineR not suitable for processing large and complex datasets?
I tried to create a simple reproducible sample showing the setup of my data

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create sample data
n_people <- 20000
years_of_observation <- 26

# Generate a data frame with all individuals born in 1945
sample_data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:n_people,
  fodelsear = rep(1945, n_people)  # All born in 1945
)

# Initialize CCI columns for ages 50 to 75
for (age in 50:75) {
  sample_data[[paste0("CCI_age", age)]] <- NA
}

# Assign CCI scores ensuring linear progression, including 99 for death
for (i in 1:n_people) {
  initial_score <- sample(c(0:13, 99), 1)  # Random starting score, including 99
  for (age in 50:75) {
    # Ensure the score does not decrease; increment based on age
    if (initial_score != 99) {
      sample_data[i, paste0("CCI_age", age)] <- min(initial_score + (age - 50), 13)
    } else {
      sample_data[i, paste0("CCI_age", age)] <- 99  # Assign 99 if the initial score is 99
    }
  }
}

# Introduce slight randomness in scores for each individual
for (age in 50:75) {
  sample_data[[paste0("CCI_age", age)]] <- pmin(sample_data[[paste0("CCI_age", age)]], 
                                                  sample_data[[paste0("CCI_age", age)]] + sample(0:1, n_people, replace = TRUE))
}

# Create sequence data
sequence_data <- seqdef(sample_data, 
                         var = 3:28,  # Adjust column indices to match CCI_age columns
                         alphabet = as.character(c(0:13, 99)), # Include 99 in the alphabet
                         missing = NA)

# Recode sequences to reduce dimensions
sequence_recode <- seqrecode(sequence_data, 
                              recodes = list("0" = c("0"),
                                             "1 CCI" = c("1"), 
                                             "2 CCI" = c("2"), 
                                             "3 CCI" = c("3"),
                                             "4+ CCI" = c("4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), 
                                             "death" = "99"))

# Recode sequences to reduce dimensions
disability_new <- seqrecode(disability_seq, 
                            recodes = list("0" = c("0"),
                                           "1 CCI" = c("1"), 
                                           "2 CCI" = c("2"), 
                                           "3 CCI" = c("3"),
                                           "4+ CCI" = c("4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), 
                                           "death" = "99"))


This is indeed related to the number of cases. You can check here for possible workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929936/problem-with-big-data-during-computation-of-sequence-distances-using-tramine/15929937#15929937

Thank you for this reply! I have tried the weightedcluster but unfortunately the aggregation still exceeds what is allowed: Error: 61872  unique sequences exceeds max allowed of  46340
Can I aggregate it more?

If your objective is to cluster the data, you may want to consider the solution proposed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63037549/1586731

Using your example sequence_data, the computation of the OM distances with INDELSLOG indel and substitution costs runs smoothly:
dom <- seqdist(sequence_data, method="OM", sm="INDELSLOG")
## [>] 20000 sequences with 15 distinct states
## [>] Computing sm with seqcost using  INDELSLOG
## [>] generated an indel of type  vector
## [>] 15 distinct  sequences 
## [>] min/max sequence lengths: 26/26
## [>] computing distances using the OM metric
## [>] elapsed time: 5.48 secs

The memory issue you are reporting with computing pairwise dissimilarities occurs when the number of dissimilarities to be computed becomes too large. Reducing the size of the alphabet and sequence lengths won't change this number but can reduce computing time.
For workarounds, see the links provided in the comments.
