# Increasing limit of unique sequences for distance matrix

Tags: traminer

I tried creating a dissimilarity matrix for a large data set and received an error stating that the number of unique sequences exceeded the allowed maximum. Is there a way to expand this limit?

```
dist_om <- seqdist(States_Wide.seq,
                   method = "OM",
                   indel= 1.0,
                   sm= costmatrix)
```

Error:

```
 [!!] seqcost: 'with.missing' set as FALSE as 'seqdata' has no non-void missing values
 [>] creating 9x9 substitution-cost matrix using 2 as constant value
 [>] 74326 sequences with 9 distinct states
 [>] checking 'sm' (size and triangle inequality)
Error: 51253  unique sequences exceeds max allowed of  46340
```

Comment: Solution to overcome this limit are currently under development. You can check here for potential workarounds in the meantime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929936/problem-with-big-data-during-computation-of-sequence-distances-using-tramine/15929937